# Роутинг страниц в SPA-приложении на основе стека ASP.NET MVC + ASP.NET Web API + AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, spa

[Проект на GitHub](https://github.com/derkode/SpaRouting)

До этого при работе с AngularJS пользовался такими ключевыми вещами как модуль, контроллер, сервис, но **роутинг** (ng-route) не использовал. Теперь же хочу создать полноценное **Single page application** со стеком `ASP.NET MVC 5 + ASP.NET Web API 2 + AngularJS`.

1) Создал **пустое** проект-веб-приложение в VS, где отметил галочки MVC и Web API:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2) Создал папку Templates, где собираюсь хранить страницы, по который будет осуществляться роутинг:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Api-контроллер пока делать не стал, но в реальности он есть, и как в подобных проектах предоставляет методы с помощью которых сервисы AngularJS добывают данные.*

Теперь сами файлы проекта:

**Index.html**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "";
}
<html ng-app="appModule">
<head>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/modules/appmodule.js"></script>
</head>
<body  ng-controller="appCtrl">
    <div>
        <a href="/#/secondpage">Second page</a>
    </div>
    <div ng-view></div>    
</body>
</html>
```

**appmodule.js**

```
var appModule = angular.module('appModule', ['ngRoute']);
appModule.controller('appCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.data = {};
});
appModule.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/secondpage', {
        templateUrl : 'Templates/secondpage',
        controller  : 'appCtrl'
    })
});
```

Но при клике на надпись «Second page» никакого перехода не происходит

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а просто в адресной строке браузера отображается (как показано на рисунке выше):

> localhost:порт/#/secondpage

**Чего еще не хватает?**

Подозреваю что какой-то конфликт происходит в RoutConfig.cs – наверное MVC так просто маршрутизацию не отдаст :). Но я где-то прочитал статью, где говорилось что установив `/#` маршрутизация AngularJS должна работать. Но не в моем случае.

[Проект на GitHub](https://github.com/derkode/SpaRouting)

Comment: а где у Вас в коде представления `<ng-view></ng-view>` в который будет осуществлен рендеринг страницы secondpage?

Comment: @Bald, я добавил  `ng-view` _(см. обн. вопроса)_, но это не помогло.

Comment: попробуй поменять ссылку на `href="#/secondpage"` или `href="#!/secondpage"`

Comment: @Grundy, не помогло. Мне кажется там какую-то настройку маршрутов в `RouteConfig.cs` надо делать.

Comment: смотри ошибки в консоли. Он просто не может шаблон подгрузить и падает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если посмотришь в консоль - увидишь ошибку загрузки шаблона, для страницы secondpage.

Ошибка происходит из-за того, что неверное указан *адрес*.

```
templateUrl : 'Templates/secondpage'
```

ангуляр для загрузки шаблона делает обычный `ajax` запрос, и так как у тебя не настроены никакие роуты для Templates, и отсутствует файл `secondpage` - получает закономерный ответ: 404 NOT FOUND

Решается все, простым добавлением расширения, чтобы адрес соответствовал адресу файла, который надо загрузить:

```
templateUrl : 'Templates/secondpage.html'
```